# How set up different polygon colours for the result of the geojson conversion into vector tiles through geojson-vt options?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, vector-tiles

I am converting geojson files into tiles in order to show a large file in a leaflet page.

However, i want to use the colours specified for every polygon in the geojson insteaf of one unique colour.

According to the documentation (https://github.com/MarsSongco/leaflet-geojson-vt-legacy) i should use the L.geojson style but I am not able to understand how.

Any ideas?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

these are the properties that are responsible for the color, please provide a sample code, because I think that you should not have any problems to assign (fillColor, сolor) properties to the objects.

```
    let colorizedMarkerOptions = {
    maxZoom: 16,
    tolerance: 3,
    debug: 0,
    style: {
        fillColor: '#1EB300',
        color: '#F2FF00',
        weight: 2
    }
};

let anyMapLayer = L.gridLayer.geoJson(json, colorizedMarkerOptions).addTo(map);
```

L.gridLayer.geoJson(YOUR_JSON, OBJECT_OPTIONS).addTo(map);

Comment: thank you, i was able to assign the colours with the vectorgrid library finally